# $ expression is not evaluated

Tags: spring-mvc, expression, modelandview

I have this code in spring jsp and I see ${message} instead of result of it.

${message}

I am setting
ModelAndView mav = null;
mav.addObject("message", "Username or Password is wrong!!");

I verified that I am using servelet 3.1. I am running pivotal 3.2

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is other way to try  jsp expression to get ModelAndView object and see if the  attribute is really passed or if the problem is expression. Looking for any tips on debugging to find why it is just printing ${message} instead of value

Comment: I just tested.  jsp getting attribute from request is giving the value, but not ${message}. Appreciate help.   The code is Message with method1 is  ${message}
   message with method 2 is   <%= (String)request.getAttribute("message") %>